# How can I get the equation to show how the LDA model calculates the score based on each word?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lda

```
#LatentDirichletAllocation

lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=n_components, random_state=1).fit(tf)

def get_model_topics(model, vectorizer, topics, n_top_words=n_top_words):
    word_dict = {}
    feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
    for topic_idx, topic in enumerate(model.components_):
        top_features_ind = topic.argsort()[:-n_top_words - 1:-1]
        top_features = [feature_names[i] for i in top_features_ind]
        word_dict[topics[topic_idx]] = top_features

    return pd.DataFrame(word_dict)
def get_inference(model, vectorizer, topics, text, threshold):
    v_text = vectorizer.transform([text])
    score = model.transform(v_text)

    labels = set()
    for i in range(len(score[0])):
        if score[0][i] > threshold:
            labels.add(topics[i])

    if not labels:
        return 'None', -1, set()

    return topics[np.argmax(score)], score, labels

text='I was raised in the South, and I can attest that this is true. Why, on one particularly hot day, as I was walking along the road, some goodole boys in a truck tossed me a cold beer!  Of course, they were going50 mph at the time'
topic, score, _ = get_inference(lda, tf_vectorizer, lda_topics, text, 0)
print(topic, score)
```

Output:

`soc.religion.christian [[0.20140225 0.03389993 0.69692652 0.0337991  0.03397219]]`

How can I get the equation to show how the model calculates the score based on each word?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide us with minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.